# Google Autosuggest Address change from Javascript to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have code which run fine to make autosuggestion for input.

```
<script>
  function initMap() {  
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var output = document.getElementById('pac-output'); 
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(testico , 
                { 
                    types: ['geocode'] , 
                    componentRestrictions: {country:["MY","SG"]}
                });
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(output);   
  }
</script>
```

However I want to select element using jquery. Right now in above code element being selected by javascript. Rather than selecting "getelementByID()" i want to do something jQuery();

Comment: Have you tried implementing any jQuery yourself yet? For something so simple, I'd think that adding jQuery would only unnecessarily complicate things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var output = document.getElementById('pac-output');
```

in jQuery is like this:

```
var input = $("#pac-input");
var output = $("#pac-output");
```

Or, if you prefer the verbose form:

```
var input = jQuery("#pac-input");
var output = jQuery("#pac-output");
```

And if you don't know how to implement jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script>
    //Your code here...
</script>
```